# Sorting tree with other column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which implements a tree using **hierarchyid** column

Sample data:

```
People             \
    Girls          \1\
        Zoey       \1\1\
        Kate       \1\2\
        Monica     \1\3\
    Boys           \2\
        Mark       \2\1\
        David      \2\2\
```

This is the order using **hierarchyid** column as sort column

I would like to sort data using **hierarchyid** but also using **name** so it would look like this:

```
People             \
    Boys           \2\
        David      \2\2\
        Mark       \2\1\        
    Girls          \1\
        Kate       \1\2\
        Monica     \1\3\
        Zoey       \1\1\
```

Is there a simple solution to do this?

Can it be done with a single `SQL` query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite your query as a recursive `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL, path HIERARCHYID)

INSERT
INTO    @table
VALUES  
        (1, 'People', '/'),
        (2, 'Girls', '/1/'),
        (3, 'Boys', '/2/'),
        (4, 'Zoey', '/1/1/'),
        (5, 'Kate', '/1/2/'),
        (6, 'Monica', '/1/3/'),
        (7, 'Mark', '/2/1/'),
        (8, 'David', '/2/2/')

;WITH   q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, HIERARCHYID::Parse('/') AS newpath
        FROM    @table
        WHERE   path = HIERARCHYID::GetRoot()
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.*, HIERARCHYID::Parse(q.newpath.ToString() + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '/')
        FROM    q
        JOIN    @table t
        ON      t.path.IsDescendantOf(q.path) = 1
                AND t.path.GetLevel() = q.path.GetLevel() + 1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        newpath
```