# Sql Hierarchy ID Sorting By Level

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchy, hierarchyid

Is it possible to sort sql data in a hierarchy by it's hierarchy id, and then for each level sort it say alphabetically?

So say we have an Employees Table that lists the organizational hierarchy based on the Employees ID

You have Bob (5) who has Phil (17) and Charlie(28) Reporting to him, and Josie (6) has Tyler (15) and Mike (56) Reporting to her.

If you sort it by HierarchyID it will look like:

Bob (/5/)
--Phil (/5/17/)
--Charlie (/5/28/)
Josie (/6/)
--Tyler (/6/15/)
--Mike (/6/56/)

But It would probably make more sense to have it look like

Bob
--Charlie
--Phil
Josie
--Mike
--Tyler

Is this possible without it getting too convoluted?

Answer (score 2):

--Will this work?  this is taken from [Sorting tree with other column in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711916/sorting-tree-with-other-column-in-sql-server-2008)

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL, path HIERARCHYID)

INSERT
INTO    @table
VALUES  
        (1, 'People', '/'),
        (2, 'Girls', '/1/'),
        (3, 'Boys', '/2/'),
        (4, 'Zoey', '/1/1/'),
        (5, 'Kate', '/1/2/'),
        (6, 'Monica', '/1/3/'),
        (7, 'Mark', '/2/1/'),
        (8, 'David', '/2/2/')

;WITH   q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, HIERARCHYID::Parse('/') AS newpath
        FROM    @table
        WHERE   path = HIERARCHYID::GetRoot()
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.*, HIERARCHYID::Parse(q.newpath.ToString() + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '/')
        FROM    q
        JOIN    @table t
        ON      t.path.IsDescendantOf(q.path) = 1
                AND t.path.GetLevel() = q.path.GetLevel() + 1
        )
SELECT  replicate(convert(nvarchar, '-'), q.path.GetLevel()) + q.name /*+ '(' + q.newpath.ToString() + ')'*/
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        newpath
```

Comment: Its a parent child relationship, as deep as it has to go. Right now currently the deepest level is 4, but it could go to 400 if we really wanted to, but who has ever heard of a menu with 400 levels.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I've found

```
declare @oldId hierarchyid, @newId hierarchyid, @parent hierarchyid

select @oldId = id_node, @parent = id_node.GetAncestor(1)
from gbs.T_Hierarchy_Activities ha
where ID = @ID_Object

select @newId = @oldId.GetReparentedValue(@oldId, ID_Node) from (
    select row_number() over(order by id_node) rn, id_node
    from gbs.T_Hierarchy_Activities ha
        cross join (select * from common.FX_Permissions() where ID_Feature = 10) p
    where ID_Node.IsDescendantOf(@oldId.GetAncestor(1)) = 1
        and ID_Level = @oldId.GetLevel()
        and ha.ID_Office = p.ID_Office
) a
where rn = @NewPosition

update gbs.T_Hierarchy_Activities
set ID_Node = case when ID_Node = @oldId then @newId else @oldId end
where ID_Node in (@oldId, @newId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you can just add a secondary sort field to the `ORDER BY` clause. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY HierarchyID, Name
```

Comment: The second order by is a tiebreaker isn't it? If there were any ties then it would sort those alphabetically. All these entries would have unique HiearchyIDs so the second sort wouldn't affect anything I don't think.

Comment: Yes, sorry misunderstood. Can you list the table definition in your question? Is HierarchyID just a string that concatenates each level separated by slashes? Is there a ManagerID field?

Comment: This was just a trivial example. The real example is for Menus (I figured Employees would be more easily understood).  Important Fields are Description (varchar) and MenuHierarchy (hierarchyID)