# HierarchyId and Alphabetical order of new record

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data, hierarchyid

I am playing with the HierarchyId columns in SQL Server in order to decide whether to use them in a new project.

I read some articles, watched some tutorials, I did some tests and the basic concepts are clear to me.

However, I have a problem inserting new records into the table.
Let's say I have such a structure:

> ```
> - Metallica (/1/)
>   - Kill em all (/1/1/)
>     - Hit the lights (/1/1/1/)
>     - Whiplash (/1/1/3/)
> - Iron Maiden (/2/)
>   - Killers (/2/1/)
> - Megadeth (/3/)
> ```

Imagine I want to insert a new song (Motorbreath) under Kill'em all, but I want to sort the list in alphabetical order.

So, my final list should be like this:

> ```
> - Metallica (/1/)
>   - Kill em all (/1/1/)
>     - Hit the lights (/1/1/1/)
>     - Motorbreath (/1/1/2/)
>     - Whiplash (/1/1/3/)
> - Iron Maiden (/2/)
>   - Killers (/2/1/)
> - Megadeth (/3/)
> ```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: May I offer some thoughts on this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1192607/Combination-of-Id-ParentId-and-HierarchyId

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899230/sql-hierarchy-id-sorting-by-level ?